# convert a datatable column date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Convert datatable date format with out any external js like moment.js or something else.

Here is the column:

```
  { "aTargets": [11], "bSortable": true },
```

Right now the dateformat is:

```
02-12-2046 7.00.00 AM
```

i want to convert it to only date.
output like:

```
02-12-2046
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use split function to split the date at space then take the first element of the result

```
"02-12-2046 7.00.00 AM".split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: Also, date is not a string by default. So don't forget to use `toString()` before using `split()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try render property. Try below code.

```
{
    "aTargets": [11], 
    "bSortable": true, 
    "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        return  date.getDate() + "-"+date.getMonth()+"-" + date.getFullYear();
    }
}
```

It may have syntax error, please fix it yourself :)

Comment: It should work. Something missing. Check this link for example http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html